# xadd not found with redis py 2.10.5

Tags: redis, redis-py

I am working with version 2.10.5 of redis-py and getting error "Redis object has no attribute xadd".

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You're using too old client, RedisPy [2.10.5](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/releases/tag/2.10.5) was released in 2015. XADD is a stream feature that has been released in Redis [5.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redis/redis/5.0/00-RELEASENOTES) was the first version having a stream data structure, Redis 5.0 was released in 2018. You should upgrade your Redis-py client to the latest version that's 3.5.3, Redis-Py [3.0.0](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/CHANGES) is the first version that supports stream data structure.